# Property "trigger" in Local Notification is not working on ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, localnotification

Local Notification 0.8.9-beta

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
id: 1,
title: 'Attention',
text: 'Simons Notification',
data: { mydata: 'My hidden message this is' },
trigger:{ at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 1000)},
```

//propert trigger is not working

});

Answer (score 0):

The following code (your code):

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: 'Attention',
    text: 'Simons Notification',
    data: { mydata: 'My hidden message this is' },
    trigger: { at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 1000)}
});
```

works perfectly fine for me. It is syntaxically correct, and follows the indications of [the Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/).

Therefore, I recommend you the following steps:

#### In your file

• Make sure that you reach the part of your code where the local notification gets scheduled.

• Make sure that you imported all the dependencies in your .ts file:

```
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
```

• Make sure the attribute `localNotifications` is properly declared in your constructor:

```
constructor(private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) {
    [...]
}
```

#### In your app

• Make sure that LocalNotifications [is properly installed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/local-notifications):

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification
npm install --save @ionic-native/local-notifications
```

• Make sure that `LocalNotifications` is properly declared in your app.modules.ts file:

```
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
```

and

```
@NgModule({
  // Some other stuff,
  providers: [
    LocalNotifications,
    // Some other providers
  ]
})
```

If you follow these steps and everything is installed properly, there is no reason for your code to fail, as it is correct syntaxically.

Comment: I'm using also this, there is a strange situation: trigger works on now and up to 50ms delay but more delay than that is not working.

Although the steps you mentioned are all done